# How does Static variable declared inside a function behave?

Tags: c++, static

I was wondering what would happen if we kinda "redefine"(that's not a good term for what is happening) a static variable.

```
#include <iostream>
void insert(int k) {
    static int jo = k;
    std::cout << jo << std::endl;
}
int main()
{   
    insert(1);
    insert(2);
}//output  1 and 1
```

I expected that the code above would have a problem, but it runs without any. At least I would expect that the 2 of `insert(2)` would go to some other memory location, but I couldn't find it. Although if we change it to:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{   
    static int jo = 1;
    std::cout << jo << std::endl;
    static int jo = 2;
    std::cout << jo << std::endl;
}// 'jo' redefinition; multiple initialization
```

We get a problem, in this case I believe that's because the two declarations *[potentially conflict](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#scope.scope-5)* and one *[precedes](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#lookup.general-2)* the other what I think don't apply to the first code of this question. What happens in the first code?

Comment: A local static variable is initialized when it is first elaborated (execution first hits that line) -- this happens on the first call to `insert` which initializes it to 1 and it stays at 1.

Comment: @wcochran I agree, but the 2 I sent as argument is totally discarded ? I was expecting it being some garbage somewhere

Comment: Yeah -- the 2 is unused in the second call. Note that `static int jo = k;` is *not* an assignment -- it is an initialized declaration. Change so that an assignment is used and you will see it change.